# existence of minimal resolutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a toric variety. A resolution of singularities $f \colon Y \rightarrow X$ is called minimal if for every resolution $g \colon Z \rightarrow X$, there is a morphism $h \colon Z \rightarrow Y$ such that $f \circ h = g$.

I know and understand that there is a minimal resolution of singularities for toric surfaces. But what about toric varieties in general? I read that minimal resolutions of toric singularities in higher dimensions might not be unique. Does anybody know an example for a toric variety that admits two different minimal resoultions?

Do minimal resolutions of singularities of toric varieties always exist? And if no, is there a nice counterexample?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's useful to separate the toric and non-toric aspects of the question.

The minimal resolution of singularities exsits for *any* surface, but in general there is no resolution that is minimal (in the sense of your defintion) for higher-dimensional varieties, because of the possibility of birational maps called *flops*.

Now the question is whether there are toric examples of flops, and the answer is that indeed there are. In fact the simplest example of a flop, the so-called *Atiyah flop*, is toric. The singular affine threefold $X=\{xy-zw\}=0$ has as its fan the "square" cone $S$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$. We get two different toric resolutions $X_i \rightarrow X \ (i=1,2)$ by subdividing $S$ into simplicial cones in two different ways, namely by including the two diagonals of the square. Note that the resulting fans are isomorphic, showing that the two varities $X_i$ are abstractly isomorphic, but they are *not* isomorphic over $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm not sure whether I understood what you explained: Is $X=\{xy-zw=0\}$ an example for a toric surface that has no minimal resoltion?

Comment: And what do you mean by "not isomorphic over X"?

Comment: Dear @claudi: no, as you noted every surface has a minimal resolution. My $X$ is a three-dimensional hypersurface in _affine_ space $\mathbf{A}^4$ with a double point at $(0,0,0,0)$. To say that the $X_i$ are not isomorphic over $X$ means there is no isomorphism between them that makes the diagram $X_1 \rightarrow X \leftarrow X_2$ (in which both arrows are the resolution maps) commute.

Comment: oh I wanted to write "an example for a toric variety that has no minimal resolution", sorry for that mistake! Thanks for your explanation, it's very helpful!